# Connecting to MySQL database in XAMPP on Mac

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am using cakePHP to connect to a database in XAMPP phpMyAdmin. I have added a new user, set the password and set the privilleges. I cannot for the life me create a connection to the database on my localhost. What I have done so far.... I have a live web server with a database. I can connect to this database no problem. I have a database running in MySQL workbench on localhost. I can connect to this no problem. This tells me that there is nothing wrong with my connection code and the problem must sit with phpMyAdmin in XAMPP. I have created a simple connection PHP script to try and connect to the database and it doesn't work. The same script can connect to my live web server and my localhost MySQL workbench database but not my XAMPP database. My connection script is as follows:

```
<?php

   $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
   // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

   // Perform a query, check for error
   if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('Glenn')"))
   {
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
   }

   mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The error message I get is;

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)Error description:

If i go to phpMyAdmin in XAMPP and go to the test database I can clearly see that this user has full access. I have tried using the host name as `127.0.0.1, localhost` and ::1. Nothing seems to work. I just dont understand why XAMPP will not let me connect to the database. I hope I'm not missing something obvious so any help will really be appreciated. [here is a screen shot of the users and their privilleges for the database test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE92r.png)

Comment: "using password: no". Did you set a password on your root account? MySQL accounts are username@hostname, and BOTH components have to match. if you set a password on the user table entry that happens to match, then that's why you're being denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the second reason why one should never use 'root' unless one knows exactly what one is doing. Only a few expirenced ones **really** know what they're doing each and every moment...

Add a specific useraccount like 'data' on your localhost and grant it the needed priviledges on your DB.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually using the username 'login' with an auto generated password that is of high complexity. This however doesn't work either. I have used the 'root' user with no password to highlight the fact that not even the admin accounts can connect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Open config.inc.php file in the phpmyadmin directory
Find line 21: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
Change it to: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your_password';
Restart XAMPP
```

Comment: i tried this solution but it did not work. Changing the password stopped all access to phpMyAdmin. Thank you for trying though.